# Return 1 if there is any 1 in row, 0 othrewise - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have data set with binary variables (1 or 0).
I want to create a new variable that get a 1 value if any of specific group of variables (X2, X3, X4 in the example below) got 1,
and a 0 otherwise.

Data illustration:

```
X1  X2  X3  X4
34  0   0   0
26  0   1   1
89  1   0   0
```

Expected result:

```
X1  X2  X3  X4  New
34  0   0   0   0
26  0   1   1   1
89  1   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test at least one `1` per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and convert to `integer`s:

```
df['new'] = df[['X2', 'X3', 'X4']].any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Or use [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['new'] = df[['X2', 'X3', 'X4']].any(axis=1).view('i1')
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['new'] = np.where(df[['X2', 'X3', 'X4']].any(axis=1), 1, 0)
```

---

```
print (df)
   X1  X2  X3  X4  new
0  34   0   0   0    0
1  26   0   1   1    1
2  89   1   0   0    1
```